# How do I override the actions of the ExoPlayer buttons

Tags: android, exoplayer

I created my layout for the ExoPlayer buttons

```
***
<ImageButton
                android:id="@id/exo_play"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:onClick="onPlayClick"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@id/exo_pause"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:onClick="onPauseClick"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_pause" />
***
```

I have a program in my program that starts and stops from the PlayerActivity. How to make the service stop when clicking on the pause button in the EcxoPlayer, and when you click on play, the service was restarted?

Code PlayerActivity

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String autor;
    private String file;
    private String img;

    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";
    static boolean isPlay = false;
    ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private TextView txtTitle;
    private RoundedImageView imgRadio;

    private ImageButton exo_pause;
    private ImageButton exo_play;

    private String internetStatus = "";

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    BroadcastReceiver serviceReceiver;
    public final static String SERVICE_PARAM = "param";
    public final static int SERVICE_STATUS = 0;
    public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "ru.myapps";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        autor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("autor");
        file = "link";
        img = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img");

        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        imgRadio = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        exo_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exo_pause);
        exo_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exo_play);

        setTitle(title);
        txtRadio.setText(title);

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);

        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0) {
            startPlayerService();

            exo_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (isPlay) {
                        stopPlayerService();

                    }
                }
            });

            exo_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(PlayerActivity.this) != 0 ) {
                        if (!isPlay) {
                            startPlayerService();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, file);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_RADIO, title);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            //Toast.makeText(context, internetStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        serviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int serviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_PARAM, 0);

                if (serviceStatus == SERVICE_STATUS) {
                    btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, filter);

        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        unregisterReceiver(serviceReceiver);
    }
}
```

I tried to implement the actions of buttons in onresume but when I pause the service it stops and the play button does not play

Comment: Why is your `setOnClickListener` in `OnResume` it should be in `OnCreate`

Comment: In the onCreate method, the same effect

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnClickListener` should be in `OnCreate`, try this and let me know:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int id;
private String title;
private String autor;
private String file;
private String img;

private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";
static boolean isPlay = false;
ImageButton btnPLayPause;
private TextView txtRadio;
private TextView txtTitle;
private RoundedImageView imgRadio;
private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;

private ImageButton exo_pause;
private ImageButton exo_play;

public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
private String internetStatus = "";

BroadcastReceiver br;

BroadcastReceiver serviceReceiver;
private AsyncTask jsonTask;


public final static String SERVICE_PARAM = "param";

public final static int SERVICE_STATUS = 0;

public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "ru.myapps";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
    title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    autor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("autor");
    file = "link_mp3_files";
    img = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img");

    RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
    RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);

    btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
    txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
    imgRadio = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

    exo_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exo_pause);
    exo_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exo_play);

    setTitle(title);
    txtRadio.setText(title);

    if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0) {
        startPlayerService();
    }

    exo_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isPlay) {
                stopPlayerService();

            }
        }
    });

    exo_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(PlayerActivity.this) != 0 ) {
                if (isPlay) {
                    startPlayerService();                        

                }
            } 
        }
    });

    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);

    registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

public void startPlayerService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, file);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_RADIO, title);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    isPlay = true;
    btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);

    if(exo_play.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {  
       exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
       exo_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}

private void stopPlayerService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
    isPlay = false;
    btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);

    if(exo_pause.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) { 
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        //Toast.makeText(context, internetStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    serviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int serviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_PARAM, 0);
            if (serviceStatus == SERVICE_STATUS) {
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, filter);

    registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    unregisterReceiver(serviceReceiver);
}

}
```

In `OnResume` you can check if it is running or not then stoo it if you would like to.

Your problem is that you never called `startPlayerService();` when `exo_play` is tapped. Please see `exo_play.setOnClickListener`. I also removed the else statement as it is unnecessary.

Comment: I inserted the code in the onCreate, but still, after I clicked on the exo_pause, the service stops, but the exo_play are not displayed

Comment: startPlayerService (); I'm using the onCreate method

Comment: I have edited my answer, I removed visibility from onclick and added it to start and stop methods

Comment: Sorry, but I tried it already. After the pause, the service stops. But the play button does not appear.

Comment: The play button quickly appears and again disappears in my opinion.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide how your code looks like now.

Comment: amended question

Comment: Ok so you have 3 buttons, `btnPLayPause`, `exo_pause` and `exo_play`. When the service is started you want to display `icon_stop` in `btnPLayPause` and make `exo_pause` visible. When the service is stopped you want to display `icon_play` in `btnPLayPause` and make `exo_play` visible. Is that correct?

Comment: btnPLayPause Can be ignored. Interested in two buttons exo_player and exo_pause. I want this: When the activation is activated, the service starts and starts playing the audio exo_pause button is visible. If you press the exo_pause, the service stops and the exo_pause become invisible, and the exo_player becomes visible. If you click exo_player, the service starts exo_player becomes invisible, and the exo_player button becomes visible

Comment: Please see my final edit. If this doesn't work then I'm sorry but I can't think of anything else that can cause it.

Comment: It still does not work. Thanks, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: I think your problem can be with `static boolean isPlay = false;` try setting it to true.

Comment: I will sort this out. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes that is your problem, you check `if (isPlay)` when pausing, then you call `stopPlayerService ();` and in `stopPlayerService();` you set `isPlay = false` so it will remain false... try my edit once more

Comment: Can you show your code how did you end up as a result?